# Moq with same argument in Setup and Verify

Tags: c#, moq

All to often I write the same argument expression in `Setup` and `Verify`. Is there a way to make a reference of them?

---

What I write:

```
var mock = new Moq<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(m => m.MyMethod(It.Is.Any<string>());
...
mock.Verify(m => m.MyMethod(It.Is.Any<string>()), Times.Once);
```

Then I have the idea that as `Setup` and `Verify` share the same parameter it should/could be moved into a common reference like so:

```
var MyMethodCall = {WHAT SHOUD BE HERE?};
var mock = new Moq<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(m => MyMethodCall);
...
mock.Verify(m => MyMethodCall, Times.Once);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a variable that holds the expression, so you can reuse it:

```
Expression<Action<IFoo>> expression = x => x.MyMethod(It.Is.Any<string>());

var mock = new Moq<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(expression);
...
mock.Verify(expression, Times.Once);
```

Comment: For future readers: If you want to do a `mock.Setup(expression).Returns("whatever");` make the expression a `Expression<Func<IFoo,string>>`.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you could use `Verifiable`, then you don't need to specify parameters in `Verify` at all. It will verify that specific verifiable `Setup` has been invoked.

```
var mock = new Moq<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(m => m.MyMethod(It.Is.Any<string>()).Verifiable();
...
mock.Verify();
```

---

IMO `Verifiable` is better choice as `Verify(Expression<>)` doesn't work with setups but invocations internally. The explanation bellow:

```
public class Example
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

public interface IExample
{
    bool Do(Example e);
}

// arrange
Expression<Func<IExample, bool>> expr = m => m.Do(It.Is<Example>(x => x.IsValid));
var mock = new Mock<IExample>();
mock.Setup(expr).Verifiable();

// act
var example = new Example {IsValid = true};
mock.Object.Do(example);
example.IsValid = false;

// assert
mock.Verify(expr, Times.Once);
```

What the outcome will be? The test will **fail**, since `Verify` will evaluate the expression after object has been changed. If you are using `Verify` then the invocation will be captured at the moment of invocation. However this is just a showcase should not happened that often :)